# (Alerting Policies) Set up custom messages

Tags: stackdriver

I'm using Google StackDriver to monitor a set of servers and websites, I have created Mail and SMS alerting policies, it is working well so far, but the mails and SMS contents aren't that easily readable for anyone that doesn't work with Stackdriver. For example, the tech team are alerted when there is an issue with one of the monitored server, but I want the information on which server to be quickly accessible without decrypting the mail or SMS. Does StackDriver provide some sort of template, or is it possible to custom the alerting messages ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Stackdriver today supports a custom documentation section where you can provide detailed instructions for your team. The documentation is part of the alert notification (not SMS), and can include information such as how to escalate, steps to mitigate the problem, steps to debug, etc.
At this time, Stackdriver does not allow you to customize the notifications.
Thanks for using Stackdriver!

Comment: could you please elaborate on this one?

Comment: based on the msg:https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#gcp_console

```
Note: An alerting policy sends an email notification when the alert is triggered and when the incident is resolved. This behavior can't be customized. However, you can set up email rules to filter your email notifications.
```

I do not see how could we alert the email format